# cssContainingText doesn't find the webelement in Angular

Tags: angular, dom, protractor

I am using [protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/) with Angular and I am looking to find a web element using `cssContainingText`, but it does not find it when I use

```
return element(by.cssContainingText('.libelle', 'lien_tst'));
```

The **HTML code** is

```xml
    <app-test-console >
        <mat-card _ngcontent-fue-c13="" class="mat-card lien ng-star-inserted" >
          <mat-card-content _ngcontent-fue-c13="" class="mat-card-content">
            <div _ngcontent-fue-c13="" class="image">
              <img _ngcontent-fue-c13="" alt="" src="assets/images/test.png">
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-fue-c13="" class="libelle"> lien_tst </div>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </app-test-console>
```

Comment: Your usage looks ok. Can you share the code where you are calling `return element(by.cssContainingText('.libelle', 'lien_tst'));`

Comment: it's fine , I found the solution , I add a response for my question . Thanks.

Comment: .Welcome to SO! I tried improving your post since it was not really accessible before. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, there is an iframe that wraps all web Elements.

```
browser.switchTo().frame('framexpath').getWebElement());
```

It works now.